# Angular Map not retrieving data

Tags: angular, ecmascript-5

I have below Model

```
export class ChartModel {
    labelsMap: Map<String, String[]>;
    LegendMap: Map<String, String[]>
}
```

I have below fields in component.ts file

```
chartModelMap = {X: ChartModel, Y: ChartModel, Z: ChartModel};
chartModelMap2 = new Map<string,ChartModel>();
```

Calling the service and assigning ChartModel object from response. (ctype is will be X or Y or Z)

```
this._chartService.getDataForBarChart(this.summaryFilterModel).subscribe(chart => {
        this.chartModelMap[ctype]=chart;
        chartModelMap2.set(ctype, chart);
        console.log('ctype',ctype,'chart:',this.chartModelMap[ctype])
        console.log('ctype',ctype,'chart:',this.chartModelMap2[ctype])
      });
    })
```

When above service called, i can see the chartModel object and their fields(legentMap, LabelMap) in the console log.

After storing it in the above function, i am taking the data in anther function. Like below

```
drawChart(chartType:string): any { // chart type will be X or Y or Z
    console.log('this.chartModelMap>',this.chartModelMap) // This is working, in console i see the data
     console.log('this.chartModelMap>',this.chartModelMap.get(chartType)) // returning undefined
 console.log('this.chartModelMap>',this.chartModelMap[chartType]) // returning undefined
 console.log('this.chartModelMap>',this.chartModelMap.size) // returning zero
console.log('this.chartModelMap>',Object.keys(this.chartModelMap)) // returning nothing
 }
```

I was really not sure what is going on. Why cant i directly get the data from MAP.
I am using angular 9 with ES5.

Expecting your help

THanks
Manivannan

**EDIT**
Below the snippet from the service and the called area

[image]

Comment: can you show the data that is logged of this.chartModelMap

Comment: thanks for your response my friend. I added a snippet from chrome console